# WPF / XAML: Change TabControl SelectedItem on Button Press

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, tabcontrol

I am searching for a pure XAML solution to the following problem:

I have a Button and a Tab Control. When i press the BUtton, the tab control should show a certain tab (so button should change SelectedIndex of Tabcontrol). I know how to solve this with code behind, but thats not what i want.

Is it possible to do this with triggers?

Comment: May I know what have you done so far to solve this?

Comment: tried it with eventtriggers routedevent "BUtton.Click" and a Storyboard with Target={Binding Source={x:Reference tabcontrolname}} TargetProperty=SelectedIndex" To="2". doesnt work because debugger says there is no object instance :/

Comment: @xb1xbv1, edit your question with adding your code excerpt, and it will be a nice question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tested this, and it works

Just take care of not using a SelectedIndex that is too big. They start at 0.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames  
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Selector.SelectedIndex)"
                Storyboard.TargetName="tabControl">
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

I can send full code if necessary, just ask in comments

Here is link to full code if needed : http://1drv.ms/1SuA8pn
Regards

Comment: thanks, looks good. but i get a xamlparseexception as soon as i add the window.triggers part. maybe the full code would be great

Comment: Just edited my post to add link to full source code. Warn me with good news please